# Casperjs ajax calls - waitForResource and parse errors

Tags: javascript, ajax, casperjs

Casperjs is a great tool. I have been able to understand certain basics. However, I am trying to tackle two issues. First, I split my code into several functions for closure reasons. I am getting a parse error. I have added the option to `verbose: true,  logLevel: "debug"` and see if it points out a line number but I get no results. Second, I want to make an ajax call, which are async. I am using `waitFor` but I read [THIS](https://ghostinspector.com/blog/making-casperjs-tests-more-reliable/.) article for a more efficient way. How can I set `waitForResource()` to track AJAX requests? and how to display parse error lines?

CODE

```
var urls = ['http://9gag.tv/'];
var casper = require('casper').create({
    verbose: true,
    logLevel: "debug"
});

function getNumberOfItems(casper) {
    return casper.getElementsInfo(".listview .badge-grid-item").length;
}

function tryAndScroll(casper) {
  casper.page.scrollPosition = { top: casper.page.scrollPosition["top"] + 4000, left: 0 };
  var info = casper.getElementInfo('.badge-post-grid-load-more');
  if (info.visible) {
    var curItems = getNumberOfItems(casper);
    if( curItems <= 60 ) {
        casper.waitFor(function check(){
          return curItems != getNumberOfItems(casper);
        }, function then(){
          tryAndScroll(this);
        }, function onTimeout(){
          this.echo("Timout reached");
        }, 10000);
    }
  } else {
    casper.echo("no more items");
  }

}

function combineArrays(x, y) {
    var result = [];
    for(var i = 0, i < page_links.length; i++) {
        result[i] = {};
        result[i].page_link = x[i];
        result[i].video_link = y[i];
    }
    return result;
}

function linkScraper(x){
    var page_links = [];
    var youtube = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++)
    { // start for loop
        casper.thenOpen(x[i], function() {
            //Scroll down for elements
            tryAndScroll(this);
            casper.then(function() {
              this.getElementsInfo('.title').forEach(function(element) {
                // skip elements that don't have a href attribute...
                if (!element.attributes.href) {
                  return;
                }
                page_links.push( element["attributes"]["href"] );
                casper.thenOpen(element.attributes.href, function() {
                  this.click('.responsivewrapper');
                }).then(function(){
                  casper.each(this.getElementsInfo('.badge-youtube-player'), function(casper, element, j) {
                    youtube.push( element["attributes"]["src"] );
                  });
                })localhost;
              });
            });
        });
    }
    return combineArrays(page_links,youtube);
}

function stringifyResult(webpages){
    //Pass link array to linkScraper
    var linksArr = linkScraper.call(this, webpages);
    //send results to php page
     server = "http://localhost:8181/hashtag_pull/lib/9GagPrivateApi.php";
     this.waitFor( function() {
         response = this.evaluate(function() {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: server,
                data: JSON.stringify(linksArr),
                //dataType: 'json',
                contentType: "application/json",
                success: function (data) {
                    this.echo("All done.");
                    return this.exit();
                    //return data.responseText;
                },
                error: function (xhr,status,error){
                    return this.echo(error);
                }
            });
         });
     });
}



casper.start().then(function() {
    this.echo("Starting");
});
casper.userAgent('Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X)');
casper.run(stringifyResult.call(this, urls));
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are many problems with your code.

## 1. Syntax error

CasperJS and PhantomJS itself won't show you where the syntax error is, but it is probably in line `for(var i = 0, i < page_links.length; i++) {`. Change `,` to `;`. And `page_links` is not defined in this line. You probably meant `x`.
For the future: CasperJS scripts are plain JavaScript. You can use online tools such as [jslint.com](http://jslint.com/) to find such bugs (and other problems with your code).

There is also a misplaced `localhost`.

## 2. `this`

`this` has many meanings depending on where it is placed.

#### a) Global `this`

Take for example the very last line:

```
casper.run(stringifyResult.call(this, urls));
```

This `this` is outside of all functions. So it refers to `window` (yes there are two separate `window` objects, one inside of the page context and one outside). It doesn't refer to `casper` which you probably expected. Use:

```
casper.run(stringifyResult.call(casper, urls));
```

*(^ non-final code: see 6.)*

#### b) jQuery callback

The `this` inside of:

```
success: function (data) {
    this.echo("All done.");
    return this.exit();
},
```

refers to the `jqXHR` object of jQuery (btw, you also cannot return something from an asynchronous function inside a function). It has nothing to do with CasperJS. Furthermore, it is impossible to call CasperJS functions from the page context (inside of `casper.evaluate()`), because the page context is sandboxed. It has no access to variables defined outside (this includes `linksArr` and `server`). See [this](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/method/evaluate.html) for more information.

## 3. Unnecessary `waitFor`

Your `waitFor` will never finish, but you probably designed it this way so that your AJAX request is sent. The problem is that the same broken request will be sent every 20 milliseconds.

## 4. Sending AJAX request

CasperJS provides a utility to send AJAX requests in the page context: [`__utils__.sendAJAX()`](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/modules/clientutils.html#sendajax). It also blocks the execution by default, so there is no need to wait for the request in a out-of-bound fashion.

```
function stringifyResult(webpages){
    var linksArr = linkScraper.call(this, webpages);

    //send results to php page
    server = "http://localhost:8181/hashtag_pull/lib/9GagPrivateApi.php";
    this.evaluate(function(server, linksArr){
        __utils__.sendAJAX(server, "POST", JSON.stringify(linksArr));
    }, server, linksArr);
}
```

*(^ non-final code: see 5.)*

## 5. Returning from asynchronous function

All `then*` and `wait*` CasperJS functions are asynchronous. By calling them, you schedule the associated step to be executed at the end of the current step.

It means that you cannot return something from `linkScraper`, because it contains asynchronous code. Or at least you cannot return the final results, because they are populated by the asynchronous code. You can however return the arrays which will eventually contain the result.

One possible fix, would be to move the combine call outside of `linkScraper`:

```
function linkScraper(x){
    var page_links = [];
    var youtube = [];
    // here are asynchronous calls
    return {pl: page_links, yt: youtube};
}
function stringifyResult(webpages){
    var linksObj = linkScraper.call(this, webpages);
    // here linksObj contains empty lists
    this.then(function(){
        // here linksObj contains populated lists
        var linksArr = combineArrays(linksObj.pl, linksObj.yt);

        server = "http://localhost:8181/hashtag_pull/lib/9GagPrivateApi.php";
        this.evaluate(function(server, linksArr){
            __utils__.sendAJAX(server, "POST", JSON.stringify(linksArr));
        }, server, linksArr); 
    });
}
```

## 6. `exit`

`casper.exit()` is immediate. So when you call it, the execution stops. You have to be careful when to call it, because it may be the case that there are still steps scheduled.

There is a way to avoid calling `casper.exit()` by not providing a callback to `casper.run()`. If you provide such a callback, there will be no automatic exit when all steps are executed.

```
casper.then(stringifyResult.call(casper, urls)).run();
```

Comment: Thank you for a well explained answer. I will make changes and keep in mind your recommendations for syntax error.

Comment: I get an empty result set from 'linkScraper'. I tried to echo results but nothing shows. Am I assigning this incorrectly to variable? I tried calling `linkScraper.call(this, webpages);`, `linkScraper.call(webpages);`

Comment: You should get an error, because `page_links` in `for(var i = 0; i < page_links.length; i++) {` is not defined. It should probably be `x`.

Comment: I changed it. I checked everything else. However, it is not displaying anything for the `linksArr`. Below in my question, I edited my code to what i have current.

Comment: Yes, there is another problem. I've updated my answer.

Comment: I made changes according to your recommendation. Yet it is still returning an empty result set. I have been working on this for a few hours but no luck. Here is my updated [GIST](https://gist.github.com/MaryCoding/adbef05159050f6312dc)

Comment: You're exiting too early. Move the `exit` and `echo` lines into the `then` block.

Comment: Alright, i had no idea it was very immediate. I have upadated my [GIST](https://gist.github.com/MaryCoding/adbef05159050f6312dc) accordingly. Will test after work.

Comment: If i want to access the array in php like `$_POST['data']` . do i need to send this like `this.evaluate(function(server, data) {
   __utils__.sendAJAX(server, "POST", data);
        }, server, {data:data});`

Comment: I'm not sure, but probably yes.

Comment: Ok, its not working for me. I tried doing this as well `this.evaluate(function(server, data) { __utils__.sendAJAX(server, "POST", {data:data}); }, server, data);` but no lukc

Comment: *not working* is not an adequate way do describe this. Did you run casperjs with the `--web-security=false` option?

Comment: Where would I input this option? Did a [google](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=casperjs+--web-security%3Dfalse) search and nothing came up relevant to this option.